# FontAwesome & Bootstrap Icons are conflicting and displaying 2 icons on top of each other?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome

My entire head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Open House Full Width Map</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A full width map for Openhouse.ca">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newMap.css">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5pF1SXoI6fZ2fVvkfweFMM7B84Syt1RM&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.962422417922454, -96.79128437499999),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            panControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
            },
            streetViewControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
            }
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
            if(zoomLevel < 4){
                map.setZoom(4);
            }
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
```

The HTML where I'm using an icon:

```
            <div class="btn-group" style="pointer-events: all;">
            <button class="btn btn-large" id="showSearch"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-large" id="showPOI"><i class="icon-home"></i></button>
            </div>
```

The result: 
[image: Overlapping icons] (the font-awesome icon, and the bootstrap icon, both overlapping each other, when I only want the font-awesome icon)

I did some googling and all other instances of my problem are 5+ months old and corrected in the font-awesome code already, but I'm stil encountering it with latest `cdn` versions of each. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try including font-awesome.css after bootstrap.css?

Comment: @Skelly OH HEY! That did it. Weird that my search results didn't turn up anything about the order of includes mattering... even on their "getting started" page, they don't say "the order matters"... anyway; thanks! Reply as an answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that the `font-awesome.css` is loaded after the `bootstrap-combined.min.css`..

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://bootply.com/62525)</kbd>